# What does a small "two white rings inside orange circle" icon mean on an app icon?

Tags: samsung, app-icons

I am using a Samsung Galaxy S21 Ultra. Why do I have some apps doubled up such as Settings, Chrome, Android System Web View, and Google Play Services?  They have a small orange icon with two circles.

[image]

Comment: AFAIK, some Samsung models have [a native Dual Messenger feature](https://www.samsung.com/in/support/mobile-devices/how-to-activate-dual-messenger-feature/), and the duplicated apps are marked with "Dual Messenger" symbol that looks like on the screenshot. However, I don't know if it also includes other apps like Settings, Chrome, Android System Web View, Google Play Services...

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Andrew, the newer models support Dual Apps.  On my system I can see other apps such as:

- Chrome
- Whatsapp

If you search for Dual in Settings, you will see the option **Dual Messenger** that allows you to use a second copy of select social apps with a second account.

[image]

If you press it, you can see the following, where you can select which apps you want to use.  And you can use a separate contacts list for these.

[image]

To disable this:

- click on the three dot menu at top right;
- press **Delete all my data**.